# Использование Form Data для всех POST запросов

Tags: javascript, node.js

Решил использовать в закрытом api сайта только form-data. Просто хочется сделать единый метод передачи как текста, так и медиа и тд.

- Есть ли какие то минусы в этом методе?
- Повлияет ли это на стабильность или безопасность передаваемых данных?
- Есть ли какие то
  уязвимости связанные с form-data?

Comment: Вы выбрали стандартизированный способ передачи данных на сервер. Да, с ним всё нормально.

Comment: p.s. что касается "безопасность передаваемых данных" то это относится к протоколу передачи, а не к способу. передача по http не безопасна, передача по https безопасна при правильной организации

Comment: https само собой